# "That [something] be" VS "that [something] is"

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm having troubles understanding the use of the "to be" infinitive in sentences like the following one:

> Although this setting is optional, it is recommended that it be configured.

It sounds good, but I'm not able to associate it to any grammar rule that I know.
I have two questions:

1. What is the grammar construct that is being used? I'd like to learn it so that I can use it correctly in the future.
2. Not knowing how to use such construct, I've often used "that it is" as an alternative form, such as in "Although this setting is optional, it is recommended that it is configured". Is this a mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the subjunctive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive